# How to make loop wait for user action and based on user input break out of loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, dom-events

I want to make loop wait for user input and based on user input. I want to continue to iterate to next incremental value or break out of loop, but the loop completes a full revolution regardless of input and when input is given. It runs the internal loop twice again, whereas I want user input for each loop/revolution and based on that, I can continue or break the loop.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      console.log(i);
      for (x = 0; x <= 1; x++) {      
          console.log("Before Event = " + x);      
          document.querySelector(".top-bar").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          var z = event.key; // Will be some key inalid input
          var a = "A";
          console.log("After Event = " + x);
          if (a !== z) {
            console.log("Expected A but Clicked = " + z);      
          }
          console.log("Outside loop = " + x);
        });
      }
    }
```

Console Log:

> 0
> Before Event = 0
> Before Event = 1
> undefined
> After Event = 2
> Expected A but Clicked = undefined
> Outside loop = 2
> After Event = 2
> Expected A but Clicked = undefined
> Outside loop = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was hard to tell what you were trying to accomplish, so I took a guess. First off, you can't combine a for-loop with input events. Instead you just have the event and keep track of how many times it gets used. To catch key presses use the `keydown` event. I used a counter called `wrong` and increment it in that console.log with `++wrong`

```js
let wrong = 0
document.querySelector(".top-bar").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  let z = event.key
  if (z !== "A") {
    console.log("Expected A but Clicked = " + z + ". You've gotten " + ++wrong + " wrong so far");
  } else console.log("RIGHT!")
});
```

```html
input a letter: <input class='top-bar' />
```

Comment: @kiran - did this help you solve your question? If so, please mark as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, it did work & later i figured i had to use nested if statements